# Memory layout in Java

Tags: java, interface, memory-layout

I went through a Java test at my high school. One question bothered me too much as I was blank as how would I solve it.

Consider the following Java code:

```
interface Pingable {
  public void ping();
}

class Counter implements Pingable {
  int count=0;
  public void ping(){++count;}
  public int val(){return count;}
}

public class Ping {
  public static void main(string args[])
  {
    Counter c=new Counter();
    c.ping();c.ping();
    int v=c.val();
    System.out.println(v);
  }          
}
```

Assume that this is to be compiled to native code on a machine with 4 byte addresses. Draw a picture of the layout in memory for counter object. Show all virtual function tables.

Comment: People are studying operating systems at high school these days?

Comment: That's a Java test? That's a **terrible** question when talking about Java. It *might* be a relevant question if you're trying to learn language implementation details, but for actual Java know-how this is *entirely* useless. Especially since nothing in the JVM spec talks about "memory layout" or "virtual function tables", they are implementation details.

Comment: Agree with @JoachimSauer. Most expert Java developers probably could not answer that question as it's completely irrelevant to learning Java. If you had asked something like 'what does it do' then I'd have downvoted as told you to run it and see, but instead I think you are the victim of a terrible teacher.

Comment: Tell your teacher that your personal java-to-native compiler does escape analysis! So it detects that it is not necessary to instantiate `Counter` and inlines everything. Then there is no `Counter` object any more, that bothers you... ;)

Comment: @isnot2bad worse than that is the fact the code won't be warmed up so it might not have anything to do with what the code looks like when actually run enough.

Comment: Your teacher is an idiot. If monomorphic call optimization kicks in there might not be a vtable. There might not be any object at all. During compilation to native code, the program might be reduced to the equivalent of just `System.out.println(2);`.

Answer (score 1):

Some important details, all completely dependant on the JVM.  This is for OpenJDK/HotSpot.

- 64-bit JVMs typically use 4-byte addresses.  Java 8 64-bit can address up to 64 GB of heap.
- each object has a header which is 12 bytes on 32-bit JVM and 16 bytes on a 64-bit JVM.
- header contains a reference to the class which contains a reference to the vtable.
- when code is warmed up simple methods can be inlined so the vtable is not used.
- while the JVM can do escape analysis and eliminate the object on the heap, it very rarely does, even in trivial cases :(

Answer (score 0):

For the following above code if you are trying to execute it in the 32-bit OS and as int is also taking 4-byte memory so simply count will consume a single 4-byte memory.